# jquery scrollTo or animate to top?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrollto

I'm using this [plugin](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/):

- Open the plugin
- if u click an image it opens up a big one. when you closing it, the BODY should scroll up.

I want to make scroll to the top on click close.!

perhaps: 
adding a class `self.$item.addClass( 'not-expanded' );` could work?but doesn't.

```
    if ($('.not-expanded').is(':visible')) {
         $('html').animate({top:'110px'}, 800 );
    }
```

Comment: could you maybe rephrase? not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand... clicking on an image does exactly that...?

Comment: I rephrased, thanks for the negative comment! I' tried my best to explain.

Comment: @Dom I you click "close" on the big image the "html, body" should scroll to top or $.scrollTo( { top:1000, left:0}, 800 ); but doen't work to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only way to close the big image is clicking on the cross in the right top corner of the div. I suggest that you go in the .js file that animate the "slideUp" of the div when you click on the cross and add a callback function to this animation with your scrolltop.

Comment: $body.animate( { scrollTop : mydiv? }); something like that on the close function?

Comment: thanks, u helped me to solve it. 

     $body.animate({scrollTop:$('#work').position().top}, 'slow');